# Возвращение значения из рекурсивной функции

Tags: c++, функции

Пишу алгоритм бинарного поиска, может кривой, но не судите, пожалуйста, вопрос заключается не в этом.

```
int binarySearch(int a[], int value, int start, int end) {
    int rHalf = (end - start) / 2 + start;
    int lHalf = rHalf + 1;
    printf("\n\n%d-%d %d-%d\n", start, rHalf, lHalf, end);
    if (start == rHalf && value == a[start]) {
        printf("start == rHalf = %d, value = %d\n", start, a[start]);
        return start;
    } else if (end == lHalf && value == a[end]) {
        printf("end == lHalf = %d, value = %d\n", end, a[end]);
        return end;
    } else if (value <= a[rHalf]) {
        binarySearch(a,value,start,rHalf);
    } else if (value >= a[lHalf]) {
        binarySearch(a,value,lHalf,end);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Тип возвращаемого значения `int`, собственно `int` и возвращаем.

Но почему то даже в случае когда срабатывает один из первых двух переключаетелей - функция возвращает `-1`, если я убираю последнюю строку, то получаю *warning* на этапе компиляции и функция возвращает `0` в результате срабатывания одного из первых двух переключателей.

В основном я пишу на *Java* и там функция возвращает управление коду сразу после команды `return`, здесь же, как я понял - даже после явного вызова `return` выполнение функции продолжается до последней сроки.

Хотелось бы знать, почему так происходит и как это можно обойти?

**UPDATE**

Очевидно я задал вопрос туманно.

Я генерирую массив с помощью `rand()` - длину и компоненты, сортирую его и запускаю поиск. Выглядит это приблизительно так:

```
init();
printArr(array, size);
mergesort(array, 1, size);
printArr(array, size);
int searchValue = rand() % MAX_VALUE;
printf("\nSearch value = %d\n", searchValue);
printf("\nSearch value = %d\n", searchValue);

printf("\nindex = %d\n", binarySearch(array, searchValue, 0, size));
```

Я думаю, код в комментариях не нуждается, все довольно прозрачно. Дело в том, что в результате выполнения я в консоли вижу следующее:

> ```
> end == lHalf = 10, value = 55
> ```

Срабатывает второй переключатель - соответственно обязано выполниться return end, значит я должен увидеть в консоли `index = 10`, но выводится при этом:

> ```
> index = -1
> ```

то есть управление передается коду не после `return end`, а после `return -1`.

Comment: warning у тебя потому, что компилятор предполагает, что когда-нибудь ни один из ифов не сработает

Comment: нет, после `return` сразу выход.

Comment: «... здесь же, как я понял ...». Вы неправильно поняли. А по поводу основного вопроса – поставьте `breakpoint` и посмотрите что, откуда и куда. Ситуация станет яснее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
} else if (value <= a[rHalf]) {
    binarySearch(a,value,start,rHalf);
```

Здесь вы рекурсивно вызываете `binarySearch`, но **не возвращаете ее значение**, а возвращаете -1, так как после этого вызова выполнение продолжается.

Пишите

```
return binarySearch(a,value,start,rHalf);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, самые очевидные ошибки всегда ускользают из виду)